# What is the difference between the single and double quotes used with the trap command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, trap

I'm trying to learn how to use the signal `trap` command on Bash. The `trap` command is quite easy to use, but the issue that hangs in my head is the importance of using single and double quotes.

- What is the difference between the single and double quotes used with the `trap` command ?
- Can you give a few simple examples that clearly show the difference between the two uses ?

Comment: There's nothing special about the `trap` command wrt. single or double quotes. If in doubt, use a function: `deb(){ echo "' ${BASH_COMMAND[@]}"; }; trap deb DEBUG`

Comment: Actually, it was the article [here that](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm) confused me. Thx your reply @mosvy

Comment: Please give example. And narrow down, where in the article.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor In the "Cleaning Up Temporary Files"

Comment: Please give example. And narrow down, where in the article. By editing question, to include an example and a quote (and reference) from the article.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor **Exp:** Also note that the shell scans the command line at the time that the trap command gets executed and also when one of the listed signals is received.

Thus, in the preceding example, the value of WORKDIR and $$ will be substituted at the time that the trap command is executed. If you wanted this substitution to occur at the time that either signal 1 or 2 was received, you can put the commands inside single quotes. **The example used in the article is not clear enough. So I'm curious about the basis of this explanation.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `trap` command just takes string to be processed as shell commands, like `eval`. That string will be processed for expansions, so the difference between double and single quotes is when the first expansions happen. In double-quotes, they happen when the trap is set, in single quotes when it triggers.

E.g. this will print `foo=1` when the `read` is interrupted, but with single quotes it would print `foo=2`:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=1
trap "echo foo=$foo; exit" INT
foo=2
read          # hit Ctrl-C here
```

Of course, even with double quotes, the resulting command gets expanded also when the trap triggers, so having `foo=$0` on the line before the trap above, would result in the script printing the script's name on interrupt.